# How to use Medical ID Feature in Healthkit?

Tags: ios8

I want to use **Medical ID** when lock is activated in IOS. I didn't get it from healthkit.
How can i access **Medical Conditions** , **Medical Notes**, **Allergies & Reactions**, **Medications** from **Healthkit Framework**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to access Medical ID.

Comment: It means we can not use medical feature in our apps. Only it is available in apple healthkit app.